# eval is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript

I could not find reason why this small code snippet is not working in IE8,

```
var a = {"ff": "test"};
eval('('+a+')');
```

I am getting error as

> ']' expected".

Comment: Is this code working in other browsers?

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Try to print out what you are eval'ing here.

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: [eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Comment: @diEcho damn, you beat me

Comment: `eval '([object Object])'`

Comment: First line should probably be `var a = '{"ff": "test"}';`

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating the object `a` to form part of the eval'd string, `a.toString()` is called, which will output `[object Object]`. What *you* want is for `{"ff": "test"};` to be concatenated into the eval'd string, so you'll need to use `JSON.stringify()` to achieve that.

Try this:

```
eval('('+JSON.stringify(a)+')');
```

Or alternatively you could just put quotes around the object declaration on the first line:

```
var a = '{"ff": "test"}';
```

Comment: What would that do? What is the meaning of the extra parentheses?

Comment: They were already part of the question, I don't know if he has a proper reason for them or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {"ff": "test"};
eval('('+a+')');
```

This is evaluated as:

```
([object Object])
```

And that's obviously not valid JavaScript. If you want to preserve a data structure, you can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

```
var a_to_json = JSON.stringify(a);
var a_from_json = JSON.parse(a_to_json);
```